# Why doesn't this array prototype work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't understand why array b[1] does not use f as a getter and setter yet array a does. yet both are arrays. what am I missing here?

```
function f(){
    print("in f");
 }


Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "0",
    { get : f, set:f});

var a=[];
var b=[1];

a[0]; // prints f
a[0]=1; //prints f
b[0]; // no print
b[0]=1; // no print

console.log("a is an array " + Array.isArray(a)); //a is an array true
console.log("b is an array " + Array.isArray(b));//b is an array true
```

Comment: Because `b`'s prototype already has a property 0 as it has one element at index 0? Your `defineProperty` is overridden.

Comment: Because `b` has an own-property 0 and `a` doesn't?

Comment: `a` has no `0` property yet because it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var a = []` does one thing: it sets `a` as an instance of a `new Array` but without any members, so the `prototype[0]` is inherited.

`var b = [1]` does two things: it sets `b` as an instance of a `new Array` (as with `a`), but then sets subscript `[0] = 1` directly (bypassing JavaScript's prototype system), which means `[0] = 1` *overwrites* the "`0`th" property, thus avoiding your `defineProperty` in `prototype[0]` entirely.

This works the same way with objects:

```
Object.defineProperty( Object.prototype, "foo", { get: f, set: f } );

var a = {};
a.foo = 1; // will print "in f"

var b = { foo: 'a' }
b.foo = 1; // will not print "in f"
```